# Running Evernote 4.0 in Ubuntu with Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, evernote

I just installed Evernote 4.0 in Ubuntu Using Wine. I find that Evernote is very slow and some features does not work such as the text encryption and file import wizard. Does any one know any hack to get these function working and how to improve the performance of Evernote ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Evernote with wine as well and its still buggy. The best option I have thus far is to install virtual box and run a version of windows, then install the windows version of Evernote. Evernote works great then, but the obvious problems are the high use of resources and the disjointed OS (between linux and windows).

I have been looking for a full featured port for Evernote to Linux and at this time I don't think there are any really good options.

NixNote and Nevernote both suck in my opinion. So feel free to try those, but I was certainly was not impressed.

One other option is to install as many browser plug-ins as you can for Evernote and something close to the same functionality. Again, not a great solution, but its what available at this time.

If anyone has any other ideas I would love to hear them, since I'm in the same boat here.

Comment: Ah also Everpad is not much better either. I just wanted to make sure I covered as many options as possible in this reply. It directly integrates with Unity, but I don't believe it has the features required by someone how uses Evernote all day every day.